# How to enable Objective-C exceptions on Xcode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, xcode4.2, try-catch

maybe I'm being daft or something but I've added a @try @catch block to my code and I'm getting a "cannot use @try with object-c exceptions disabled" error that prevents compilation...

How do I turn it on? I've searched all around, added the exception breakpoint thing and no results...How do I do this?

Comment: If you are using `@catch` to recover from exceptions, **you are doing it wrong**.   Exceptions are *not* to be used for anything but unrecoverable errors.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check if you have enabled exceptions on the project and/or target build settings.
Project Navigator -> select project or target -> build settings -> Enable Objective-C Exceptions
[image: exceptions setting]